# Codeigniter4 shows You must use the "set" method when running update query even I used "set" method

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

My query as follows

```
function reset_attempt($usr_id, $attempt = 0)
{
    if (!$usr_id)
        exit("No user found");
    $builder = $this->table($this->table);
    $builder->set('usr_attempt', $attempt);
    $builder->set('usr_lock', NULL);
    $builder->where("usr_attempt > ", $this->max_attempt);
    $builder->where($this->primaryKey, $usr_id);
    echo "<br> Query: " . $builder->getCompiledUpdate(false);
    exit();
    // $builder->update($this->table);
}
```

Then I am getting the following error message

**`CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException #8`**

`You must use the "set" method to update an entry.`

Comment: It is ok, working. I have used this form in other queries

Comment: Here `$this->table` is property of the current class and `$this->table()` is method of inherited class. [Click here for more information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.properties-methods)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked

```
class UserModel extends Model
{
   // Property used to connect with database
   protected $db;

   
   function __construct()
   {
       // Connedt with database
       $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
   }

   function reset_attempt($usr_id, $attempt = 0)
   {
        if (!$usr_id)
            exit("No user found");

        // Call method table() with $this->db
        $builder = $this->db->table($this->table);
        $builder->set('usr_attempt', $attempt);
        $builder->set('usr_lock', NULL);
        $builder->where("usr_attempt > ", $this->max_attempt);
        $builder->where($this->primaryKey, $usr_id);
        echo "<br> Query: " . $builder->getCompiledUpdate(false);
        exit();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Query: UPDATE `users` SET `usr_attempt` = '0', `usr_lock` = NULL WHERE `usr_attempt` > 2 AND `usr_id` = '1'
```